# How to convert breeze densevector to seq or array

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I need to convert breeze Densevector to seq or array so that I can use zipWithIndex to get index of each element.

Answer (score 0):

```
import breeze.linalg._
val a = DenseVector(1,2,3,4,5)
val arr = a.toArray()
```